# How do I return string when using operators in php?

Tags: php, bash, logical-operators

I know that it is possible to echo value and execute functions when using operators like this:

```
function echoTadaa() {
    echo "taTaaa";
}
echo true && echoTadaa();
```

**Result is:** taTaaa

But is it somehow possible to save string (any) value into variable when using operators?

```
$var = true && 'tadaaa';
var_dump($var);
```

**Result is:** bool(true)

**Expected result is:** string(6) "taTaaa"

Comment: What's all this for?

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense: The result of a boolean operator is a boolean, why would it be a string? And why would you want it to be a string?

Comment: I want it to be string because i do not want too write too many lines of codes. I know about ternary operators but we can't use them in our team. We have created our own standards to make the code readable. This is kind of a joke. I want to write ternary operators without using ternary operators.

Comment: @u_mulder why did you gave me negative rating? Seriouesly? This is a legit question.

Comment: What makes you think that it is me?

Comment: I am sorry if it wasnt you. You commented first and there was no one else here for some time.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
function echoTadaa() {
    return "taTaaa";
}
$str = true . echoTadaa();
```

https://3v4l.org/WFb0f

returns "1taTaaa" where 1 = true

Comment: This is really cool. `echo true . echoTadaa();` but I can't use that. I want to save the value of echoTadaa into variable. I do not want to echo it right away.

Comment: @Michal Now it saves to $str instead.

Comment: Wow. But when you change true to false. It also saves it to string.

Comment: You lost me there...

Comment: I am so sorry. :D

Comment: I want to write ternary operator without using ternary operator. So instead of `$var = something ? is : not` I want to write `$var = something && is`

Answer (score 1):

i do not really know why do you want this, but you can do it this way:

```
if(true && $a= "hello"){

}
var_dump($a);    //string(5) "hello"
```

if condition is met, then assignement will be made.
but in that situation you could assign $a var within if condition..

alternatively you can use ternary operator:

```
$a = true ? "yes" : "no";
```

demo here: https://3v4l.org/i6Hnf

> This is kind of a joke. I want to write ternary operators without using ternary operators.

Well you can't do exactly this:

```
$a = true && "something";
echo $a;
```

because evaluating will always return bool value, therefore var $a will contain bool, not your string.

you can do some obfuscation to make code look like it works this way
like here is explained: https://www.thc.org/root/phun/unmaintain.html

Comment: Exactly. I want to write ternary operators without using ternary operators.